# Very High Resolution Images in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

At the end of this question is an SSCCE to display a 24000x12000 Miller projection of satellite imagery on an HTML5 canvas. It has a couple problems:

1. Rather than showing the entire image in one screen as I desire only a small section of the upper left corner is displayed.
2. The image suffers from extreme pixellation that should not appear at the scale displayed because the image is very high resolution

[image]

- The image used is available at [Wikimedia](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Whole_world_-_land_and_oceans_12000.jpg). I renamed it "world.jpg".
- This is not a normal web application and the large image will not be downloaded during application execution so any advice to not require downloading such a large image is moot.
- The application will dynamically zoom into various map areas, thus the large image size.
- In the real code I use an external stylesheet and javascript file. I integrated them into the html solely for the SSCCE.

This is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>The Earth</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function draw() {
   var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
   var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
   var map = new Image();
   map.src = "world.jpg";
   map.onload = function() {
      var width = window.innerWidth;
      var height = window.innerHeight;
      ctx.drawImage(map, 0, 0, width, height);
   };
}
</script>
<style>
html, body {
  width:  100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
#canvas {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="draw();">
   <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried it on different browsers? The pixellation sounds like a bug or optimization in the browser code. You are talking about a very big image (800 MB uncompressed), and the abilities of different browsers with such images may differ.

Comment: Chromium and the Ubuntu browser and produce similar results.

Comment: This may be a very stupid question, but are you sure you downloaded the huge version of the image. Your link points to a low-res preview. The image file should be around 20 MiB as a jpeg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the version of context.drawImage that clips and scales the original image:

```
context.drawImage(
    sourceImage,
    clipSourceAtX, clipSourceAtY, sourceClipWidth, sourceClipHeight,
    canvasX, canvasY, canvasDrawWidth, canvasDrawHeight
)
```

For example, assume that you are focusing on coordinate [x==1000,y==500] on the image.

To display the 640px x 512px portion of the image at [1000,500] you can use drawImage like this:

```
context.drawImage(

    // use "sourceImage" 
    sourceImage

    // clip a 640x512 portion of the source image at left-top = [1000,500]
    sourceImage,1000,500,640,512,

    // draw the 640x512 clipped subimage at 0,0 on the canvas
    0,0,640,512            
);
```

A demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/MtAEY/

[image]

Comment: function draw() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var map = new Image();
    var mapWidth=map.width;
    var mapHeight=map.height;
    map.src = "world.jpg";
    map.onload = function() {
        var width = window.innerWidth;
        var height = window.innerHeight;
        ctx.drawImage(map, 0, 0, 24000, 12000, 0, 0, width, height);
        };
    }

Comment: and there was no change. Sorry, I cannot seem to get any newlines or code blocks to appear in comments. when I hit enter the comment gets added prematurely.

Comment: I've added an example to my answer. ;-)

Comment: Thanks again markE. Although I'll probably be able to use some of the zoom code you wrote the problem of how to display the full resolution image within the available space of the browser window remains.<br/>What I'm doing is creating a geographic quiz where a certain feature, let's say the Himalayan Mountains, are asked for and then six points on the full map are marked, only one of which is the Himalayas, and the user selects one of the marks.

Comment: If the correct mark is chosen then the system zooms into the feature where it will be outlined (probably with a manually drawn overlay) and given additional info about the feature. So, the requirements are

Comment: 1) Display the full high-resolution map using all available browser window space and maintaining aspect ratio<br> 2) Overlay some icons on the map<br>3) When the user selects the correct icon zoom in on the area adding additional overlays.<br><br>The specifics of the area zoomed into are not up to the user.

Comment: Understood...use the extended version of drawImage as in my example.  The extended drawImage will clip and zoom for you. You can, of course, control the zooming in code rather than let the user zoom.  Good luck with your project!

Comment: At this point all I really need is #1. Displaying an entire high-resolution image in a canvas appears to be somewhat difficult. What I need is the identical appearance to displaying the map directly in the browser by navigating to http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8f/Whole_world_-_land_and_oceans_12000.jpg but it needs to be embedded in a canvas for the various manipulations.

Comment: OK, here is a function that does #1: Takes in the original image width/height and the destination area (canvas) width/height.  It returns a scaling factor that you can multiply the original image width & height by to maintain aspect ratio in the destination area.  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/nbkUh/

Comment: OK, thanks for the help markE! Based on your code I derived what I was looking for. The fundamental problem was that in the original code posted I never set the canvas size explicitly. Apparently in that situation the canvas will dynamically size to whatever is needed to display the content and the last four parameters of the 9-argument overload of drawImage get ignored. I'm a little fuzzy on the details but the high-res map fits the size of the screen like it should. I set the canvas size equal to window.inner{width,height} and used your scaling function it works now!

Comment: '<script type="text/javascript">
  function draw() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var map = new Image();
    map.src = "world.jpg";
    map.onload = function() {
        var width = window.innerWidth;
        var height = window.innerHeight;
        canvas.width=width;
        canvas.height=height;
        var mapWidth=map.width;
        var mapHeight=map.height;'

Comment: `       var scale=scalePreserveAspectRatio(mapWidth,mapHeight,width,height);
        ctx.drawImage(map, 0, 0, mapWidth, mapHeight, 0, 0, mapWidth*scale, mapHeight*scale);
    };
  }
  function scalePreserveAspectRatio(imgW,imgH,maxW,maxH){
      return(Math.min((maxW/imgW),(maxH/imgH)));
  }
</script>`

Answer (score 1):

Here's the working javascript code, formatted nicely.

```
function draw() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var map = new Image();
  map.src = "world.jpg";
  map.onload = function() {
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.width=width;
    canvas.height=height;
    var mapWidth=map.width;
    var mapHeight=map.height;
    var scale=scalePreserveAspectRatio(mapWidth,mapHeight,width,height);
    ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    ctx.drawImage(map, 0, 0, mapWidth, mapHeight, 0, 0, mapWidth*scale, mapHeight*scale);
  };
}
function scalePreserveAspectRatio(imgW,imgH,maxW,maxH){
  return(Math.min((maxW/imgW),(maxH/imgH)));
}
```

The key is the two lines

```
canvas.width=width;
canvas.height=height;
```

Simply setting these to 100% in CSS doesn't work, the 100% is apparently not 100% of the inner dimensions of the window as I assumed. Since these dimensions are dynamic they must be set via JS not CSS.